# GoogleTransport class problem

Tags: java, google-api

i'm using a maven project with following dependency :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client-googleapis-auth-clientlogin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
    </dependency>
```

when i run following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.clientlogin.ClientLogin;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
         HttpTransport transport = GoogleTransport.create();
           // transport.addParser(new JsonCParser());
            try {
              // authenticate with ClientLogin
              ClientLogin authenticator = new ClientLogin();
              authenticator.authTokenType = "ndev";
              authenticator.username = "....";
              authenticator.password = "....";
              authenticator.authenticate().setAuthorizationHeader(transport);
              // make query request
              HttpRequest request = transport.buildGetRequest();
              request.setUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v1/query");
              request.url.put(
                  "q", "select count(*) from [bigquery/samples/shakespeare];");
              System.out.println(request.execute().parseAsString());
            } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
              System.err.println(e.response.parseAsString());
              throw e;
            }

    }
}
```

i get below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing required low-level HTTP transport package.
Use package "com.google.api.client.javanet".
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport.useLowLevelHttpTransport(HttpTransport.java:129)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport.<init>(HttpTransport.java:187)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleTransport.create(GoogleTransport.java:58)
    at com.example.clientlogin.App.main(App.java:18)
```

what is the problem with GoogleTransport class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick googeling resulted in [maven for com.google.api.client.javanet.nethttpresponse](http://mavenhub.com/c/com/google/api/client/javanet/nethttpresponse) Try adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
  </dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client-javanet</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
  </dependency>
```

to your POM file

Comment: thank you this did the trick-however i got an error saying {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}

Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
 at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:209)
 at com.example.clientlogin.App.main(App.java:32)

Comment: i used correct username and password so why is this error raised?

Comment: is it b/ i comment line  transport.addParser(new JsonCParser()); ? i can't find class JsonParser

Comment: Sorry I can't help you on this on. Try making a new question to get new help.

Answer (score 0):

this question is pretty old, but I've added some updates to our Java Google Client Lib + BigQuery samples (here: http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/samples/java/gettingstarted/BigQueryJavaGettingStarted/).

Comment: Is the new code you posted taking the OAuth approach which was not the approach in the original code?

Comment: Exactly - ClientLogin (i.e. username and password) has been deprecated for all Google APIs. Some (most?) Google APIs may no longer suppoert the username/password approach at all anymore. See: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps